# Detect scroll to bottom of div and load new posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using this method to detect the end of two div columns and load new posts. It is working. But the problem is, first it loads five posts by default function, then when user scroll down it loads the next five posts(2nd phase) at least 10 times. than when you scroll more down, it loads next 5 posts(3rd phase) again at least 10 times. Otherwise the function is good.

```js
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.div1').height() - $(window).height()) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    $('#loadmoreinstagram').remove();
                document.getElementById("instagramresponse").innerHTML = document.getElementById("instagramresponse").innerHTML+this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo $settings['URL']; ?>getdata.php?type=" + $('#type').last().val() + "&page=" + $('#page').last().val() + "&lasttime=" + $('#lasttime').last().val(), true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
     if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.div2').height() - $(window).height()) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    $('#loadmoretwitter').remove();
                document.getElementById("twitterresponse").innerHTML = document.getElementById("twitterresponse").innerHTML+this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo $settings['URL']; ?>getdata.php?type=" + $('#typetwitter').last().val() + "&page=" + $('#pagetwitter').last().val() + "&lasttime=" + $('#lasttimetwitter').last().val(), true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
});
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `window.scroll` event fires many times for one "scroll". you can see this by simply logging the events by pasting the following into your console.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {console.log('scroll')})
```

To fix this, you need to block your request from firing many times in a row in a short period of time. This is called debouncing. Underscorejs has a great builtin function for it, but a quick google will yield lots of resources for writing your own. Code below using the underscorejs function solves your problem.

```
var debouncedFn = _.debounce(function() { console.log('scroll')}, 100)
$(window).scroll(debouncedFn)
```

Learning about debounce https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

for your application:

```
</script>
  function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
      var timeout;
      return function() {
          var context = this, args = arguments;
          var later = function() {
              timeout = null;
              if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
          };
          var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
          if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
      };
  };

  function handleScroll() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.div1').height() - $(window).height()) {
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          $('#loadmoreinstagram').remove();
                  document.getElementById("instagramresponse").innerHTML = document.getElementById("instagramresponse").innerHTML+this.responseText;
              }
          };
          xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo $settings['URL']; ?>getdata.php?type=" + $('#type').last().val() + "&page=" + $('#page').last().val() + "&lasttime=" + $('#lasttime').last().val(), true);
          xmlhttp.send();
      }
       if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.div2').height() - $(window).height()) {
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          $('#loadmoretwitter').remove();
                  document.getElementById("twitterresponse").innerHTML = document.getElementById("twitterresponse").innerHTML+this.responseText;
              }
          };
          xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo $settings['URL']; ?>getdata.php?type=" + $('#typetwitter').last().val() + "&page=" + $('#pagetwitter').last().val() + "&lasttime=" + $('#lasttimetwitter').last().val(), true);
          xmlhttp.send();
      }
  }

  var debouncedScroll = debounce(handleScroll, 100)
  $(window).scroll(debouncedScroll);


</script>
```

Comment: I really appreciate you answering my question. But the problem is I am a designer trying to edit a template delivered by someone else. Can you please edit my script and add the code there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if you're using jquery, you do something like this:

```
$.get(url).done( result => {
  // do stuff when ajax is done
})
```

but this setup you have here seems to rely solely on the users' scrolling action to activate the stuff to do in `done`. So I'm not sure what to tell you other than send it back to the developer (according to a comment you made elsewhere).

A regular implementation of jquery would be something like:

```
<script>
    var working = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.div1').height() - $(window).height() && !working) {
            working = true;
            $.get( url ).done( result => {
                $('#loadmoreinstagram').remove();
                $("#loadmoreinstagram").html = $("#loadmoreinstagram").html + result.responseText;
                working = false;
            } )
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.div2').height() - $(window).height() && !working) {
            working = true;
            $.get( url ).done( result => {
                $('#loadmoretwitter').remove();
                $("#loadmoretwitter").html = $("#loadmoretwitter").html + result.responseText;
                working = false;
            } )
        }
    });
</script>
```

You can see the differences, that your dev isn't using jquery to make the hard stuff easy.